# Scale and Transform nodes behaving incorrectly in compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

i'm working on an node-based algorithm for pixelating an image and then applying a dithering mask to it using the compositor.

the issue i've run into is very simple:
render image, 1536x2048
scale by half, to 768x1024 using scale or transform node
pixelate (all good, pixel perfect, at the expected size but surrounded by a transparent border, as expected)
scale by two, back up to 1536x2048 - at this point, one single pixel is missing along the right hand edge (+x) and top edge (+y), replaced by transparency instead

this shouldn't be a rounding issue, since both dimensions are divisible by two. furthermore, i've tried translating the result at the same time in order to avoid scaling around the center point of the image rather than the corner, to no effect.

i've also checked and this missing line of pixels is accompanied by a line missing about halfway through the image (as over the rest of the image, the enlarged 'pixels' for the pixelation effect are all correctly 2x2).

since there doesn't seem to be a way to directly write a new compositing node with shader code or python to directly read every other pixel, then apply my dithering algorithm (as I've done previously in UE4), i'm at a loss. is there some quirky way to make the scale node scale the image correctly? or does it just not work accurately enough?

thanks